# Android: monitor and get list of apps with higher priority

Tags: android

I'm working on a sms based application.

I use android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED and android:priority="999" to handle received sms.

it works ok. but if user use GoSMS, my app cant receive sms because its higher priority.

is there a way to monitor and show the list of apps with equal o higher priority in a dialog box?

**EDIT:**
now, I use this code:

```
PackageManager pmg = getPackageManager();
Intent intent = new Intent("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
List<ResolveInfo> activities = pmg.queryBroadcastReceivers(intent, 0);

for (ResolveInfo ri : activities) {
    Log.i(TAG, "app name: " + ri.loadLabel(pmg));
}
```

I can get all packages that uses "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED".

**1) but I need to get packages that set   or higher than 999**

and

**2) this return Duplicate package nameg because in some packages, different activities use receiver.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [queryIntentActivities](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#queryIntentActivities%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) passing Intent and flags to get the list of the activities that can resolve the intent. Once you get the list, you can use [priority](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ResolveInfo.html#priority) from `ResolveInfo` to get the priority of that activity. Priorities range between -1000 to 1000. So GoSMS has set it to 999 which is the highest.

Comment: thanks a lot.
I post a simple code on my question.
but I couldn't filter apps by priority

Comment: Do you get the list of activities in the List? You need to check for ri.priority to get the prority of each.

Comment: for some reason I get priority 0 for each activity